# Arc Hydro 2.0 for use with ArcGIS 10.1 (or later) for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arc-hydro

I have ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop and the toolbox of Arc Hydro 1.1 beta.

I want to find and donwload the **Arc Hydro 2.0** for use with ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop but, after research on the net, I cannot find it.

I think that the new version is now released so where can I download it?

Comment: archydro has a [dedicated support forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/88-Arc-Hydro) that may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the **[Arc Hydro home page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/hydro/01vn0000000s000000.htm)** only has a link to Arc Hydro 2.0 (which I have not downloaded).

However, **Arc Hydro 10.2** was made available for download via ftp in August 2013.

If you have any trouble locating/installing it, you may want to visit **[Esri's ArcHydro Discussion Forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/89913-archydro-for-ArcGIS-10.2)**.

Answer (score 2):

You can download ArcHydro 2.0 from here: https://mft.esri.com/EFTClient/Account/Login.htm

You have to login with: 
Username: ADSRiverHydraulics    Password: ADSRiver.2014

After login and confirmation for Java, you can find folder ArcHydro -> Setup in right window and search for installer for your version of ArcGIS. It is free for download if you have ArcGIS licence. But watch out, password is changed every 6 months, but you can find actual pass on forums.

Comment: Or try http://downloads.esri.com/archydro/archydro/